# accidentally committed a different project into git repository

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed a different project into git repository which changed the complete structure of my repository how can i revert to the previous revision and get everything back. Please help me
I just committed a project from the eclipse using force option which was a different project by adding a remote path and it changed everything.

Comment: Using force, e.g., `--force`?  The "force" option gives Git permission to destroy data (which is why you always stop and think before using it).  What does the history of your repo look like?  Do you have a link?

Comment: it had a main directory like dev->project name-> 5 different folders with projects in them. but now everything is gone and now i have only my new project there which i committed there by using eclipse and force option.

Comment: What does the **history** look like?  You say GitHub, is it a public repo?

Comment: No its a private repository. actually i just changed something on the server repository and what i want is just the server repository to have the previous revision i just want to remove everything what i did on the server. Because other projects which were there were really important. How can i take server back to previous revision.

Comment: did you end up resolving this? I have a similar problem, but I don't think reset will do it. You basically have the git history of BOTH projects, now in one. Not sure how to undo it, as it's not just one commit.

Comment: Well in my case i just commit the original project again and it again changed the structure of the project so wrong project files just gone away. But i was unable to find specific solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made one `commit` and you want to revert it (and it's still the latest one), you can do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This requires that you have not `push`ed it yet. You will lose the latest commit PERMANENTLY.

If you have pushed it, you'll have to revert it:

```
git revert <commit-id>
```

Get the commit id from `git log`.

I haven't got a git command line here, and haven't used it for a little while, so apologies if there are any typos/errors in the above, but I think it should work :)

Comment: It is giving me this error now with the command git revert <commit-id>  error: Your local changes would be overwritten by revert.
hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: revert failed

Comment: That sounds like you have changes that are not submitted. To get rid of them (permanently), you can do `get reset --hard HEAD` (without the ^ in the answer above: Reset to HEAD/latest commit).